# *nix way to Multiply lines after ','

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed, tr

I have a text file that i need to adjust so i can input it into a database.

However, the format of the file is, while consistent, not really usful when wanting to put them into tables.

```
allow any 123.123.123.1,2,3 22,443
```

what i need afterwards is something like

```
allow any 123.123.123.1 22
allow any 123.123.123.1 443
allow any 123.123.123.2 22
allow any 123.123.123.2 443
allow any 123.123.123.3 22
allow any 123.123.123.3 443
```

Because the Text file is pretty old and more than 1000 lines long (one of the reasons i want to put it into our database) it would be very tideous to do it manually.

Is there a short way to do this with text processing tools like sed, tr, etc.?

Comment: Guessing the dot in the final line is a typo?

Comment: @123 no, [i just looked it up](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19434/how-to-deal-with-abbreviations-at-the-end-of-a-question) ;)

Comment: I meant in the example code before `443`

Comment: Oh, Thanks :D I misssed that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could just use brace expansion

```
printf "%s\n" "allow any 123.123.123."{1,2,3}" "{22,443}


allow any 123.123.123.1 22
allow any 123.123.123.1 443
allow any 123.123.123.2 22
allow any 123.123.123.2 443
allow any 123.123.123.3 22
allow any 123.123.123.3 443
```

Could use perl to generate and run brackets

```
perl -ne 's/[^\.\s]+,[,\S]+/{$&}/g;s/[^{}\n]+(?![^{]*})/"$&"/g;print `printf "%s\n" $_`' f
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! If I were to use this solution, i would still need a way to place the brackets around them. While i am not very versed in Regular Expressions, this should be possible with something like sed, right?

Comment: If i find a way to transform the lines from the given format to yours with sed, i will post it here and accept this as an answer, unless someone comes up with a better solution.

Comment: @Sundeep all the lines are formatted like this, your solution should work if i find a way to add the quotation marks and the brackets.

Comment: @Laurenzebs Added a way to add the brackets, provided it is always the same format

Comment: While i like @Inian 's solution, as it is tailored for mi situation, i find this to be more applicable in case of different formats for other users, so i will choose this as answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I came up with an `Awk` script as follows, to get the job done for you.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk

{
    n1=split($3,arr1,".")
    n2=split(arr1[n1],arr2,",")
    n3=split($4,arr3,",")

    k=arr1[1]"."arr1[2]"."arr1[3]

    for(i=1;i<=n2;i++) {
        for(j=1;j<=n3;j++) {
            print $1,$2,k"."arr2[i],arr3[j]
        }
    }
}
```

Put it up in a file called `script.awk` and run it as

```
awk -f awkscript.awk file
allow any 123.123.123.1 22
allow any 123.123.123.1 443
allow any 123.123.123.2 22
allow any 123.123.123.2 443
allow any 123.123.123.3 22
allow any 123.123.123.3 443
```

The idea is to split the contents of `$2` by `.` first to get the last portion alone `1,2,3` which can be accessed as `arr1[n]`, meaning the last element of the array that is formed after the split. Then the comma-separated element is now split by `,` and stored in array `arr2` and same way for the `$4` record. A variable `k` is created just to store the first three elements in first `split()`, i.e. just `123.123.123`

Now a loop is made across the array elements formed to print the elements as needed.

Comment: While i like this answer (it was the one i used first), @123 's answer is more applicable for others, so i will be choosing his answer as the one, but still, Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

Just for the fun of sed (GNU sed version 4.2.1):

`sed -E -fallow.sed | sort`

With allow.sed:

```
s/^([^\n]+[^,[:digit:]])([[:digit:]]+(,[[:digit:]]+)*),([[:digit:]]+)([^\n]*)$/\1\2\5\n\1\4\5/;
:a;
s/^([^\n,]+[^,[:digit:]])([[:digit:]]+(,[[:digit:]]+)*),([[:digit:]]+)([^\n]*)\n(.*)$/\1\2\5\n\6\n\1\4\5/;
ta;
s/^([^,]+)\n(.*,.*)$/\2\n\1/;
ta;
```

- Look for comma-separated groups of numbers.
- double the line

  - removing the numbers before the last comma in one copy
  - removing the number after the last comma in the other copy
  - removing the last comma in both copies
- start a loop here
- do the same thing for what is before the first newline
- keep what is after the first newline
- loop if something was replaced
- move a comma between newlines (if any) to the front
- loop if there was one

Output:

```
allow any 123.123.123.1 22
allow any 123.123.123.1 443
allow any 123.123.123.2 22
allow any 123.123.123.2 443
allow any 123.123.123.3 22
allow any 123.123.123.3 443
```